# C# - How to populate a custom class array containing integer primitives?

Tags: c#

I have a simple C# program that contains a `Coord` class that stores an integer `x` and `y` value. I want to treat the `Coord` class like an array, as shown in the Main method. I have seen similar approaches to this in C++ and I would like to know the C# equivalent.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lab6 {

    class Coord {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    class Program {
   
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            Coord[] c = {{1, 2}, {5, 8}, {3, 40}, {6, 3}, {15, 12}, {1, 5}};  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need lots of `new Coord` in there. Or https://dotnetfiddle.net/uYD5te .

Comment: There is not a C# equivalent. C++ "works" because you can set contiguous memory directly (and unsafely). C# requires object initialization, and you have to specify the property names.

Comment: @DStanley since OP is not married to array then collection initialization (for they own collection) will give almost exact syntax they want similar how one initialize `Dictionary<int,int> d = new Dictionary<int,int>{{1, 2}, {5, 8}, {3, 40}, {6, 3}, {15, 12}};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put instances of Coord class in the `Coord []`

```
           Coord[] c = new Coord[4];
            
            c[0] = new Coord(1,3);
            ....
```

Or a better way

```
 Coord[] c = {new Coord(1,2),new Coord(1,6)};
```

Dont forget to add the constructor and initialize the fields

```
 public  Coord(int x,int y){
          this.x = x;
          this.y = y;
    }
```

Comment: Requires adding the constructor, but yes, this is the best option.

Answer (score 2):

In C# 9.0 (.NET 5), a [record type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/exploration/records) would be best for this situation:

```cs
// Declaration
record Coord(int X, int Y);

// Implicit "new".
Coord[] c = new Coord[] { new(1, 2), new(5, 8) };
```

`new()` ([with the type omitted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#fit-and-finish-features)) was also introduced in C# 9.0. This might get you closer to what you wanted originally.

#### Record types

This wasn't part of your question, but if you want immutable data, records are the way to go in new versions of C#. Positional records, like in the example above, are immutable: I don't how you plan on using your `Coord` type, but if you don't change the x or y value after instantiation, an immutable type is probably what you want.

If you are unable to use .NET 5, you might consider using a struct instead, for similar reasons.

From the record type docs (emphasis added):

> You use `class` definitions to create object-oriented hierarchies that focus on the responsibilities and behavior of objects. You create `struct` types for data structures that store data and are small enough to copy efficiently. **You create records when you want value-based equality and comparison, don't want to copy values, and want to use reference variables.**

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C#9, you can instead A. use a `record` class and B. rely on target-typed new with the generated constructor:

```cs
public record Coord(int X, int Y);

public void YourMethod() {
   Coord[] c = { new(1,2), new(2,3) };
}
```

This also has the benefit that you can deconstruct the points into variables, which feels natural for a `Coord` type:

```cs
Coord[] c = { new(1,2), new(2,3) };
var (x, y) = c[0];
// you get withers too! 
var cNew = c[0] with { X = 5 };
```

Without records you can still use target-typing so long as you have an appropriate constructor.

```cs
class Coord {
    public int X { get; } // you should use properties, not exposed fields
    public int Y { get; } 
    public Coord(int x, int y) => (X, Y) = (x, y);
}

// later 
Coord[] c = { new(1,2), new(2,3) };
```

Or the best of all worlds (depending on your viewpoint), a *mutable* `record` with `with`ers, deconstruction and simple target typing:

```cs
record Coord(int X, int Y) {
    public int X { get; set; } = X;
    public int Y { get; set; } = Y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do with the code **as-is** looks like this:

```
Coord[] c = {
    new Coord() {x=1,y=2},
    new Coord() {x=5,y=8},
    //...
};
```

We can improve slightly on this by adding a constructor:

```
class Coord 
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Coord(int X, int Y) {x = X; Y=y;}
}
```

Which gets us to here:

```
Coord[] c = {
    new Coord(1,2),
    new Coord(5,8),
    //...
};
```

But once you're open to changing the code for the type we can do *all kinds of things*:

```
class Coord 
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Coord(int X, int Y) {x = X; Y=y;}

    public static IEnumerable<Coord> SeqFrom2DIntArray(int[,] input)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<input.GetUpperBound(0);i++) Console.WriteLine(b[x,0]);
        {
            yield return new Coord(input[i,0], input[i,1]}; // can throw an exception if the input is bad
        }
    }
}
```

And now you can create your Coord objects like this:

```
//must be a separate line/variable/object for the initializer
int[,] b = {{1, 2}, {5, 8}, {3, 40}, {6, 3}, {15, 12}, {1, 5}}; 
var c = Coord.SeqFrom2DIntArray(c);
```

Or if you *really* need an array (hint: very often IEnumerable by itself is enough and will perform much better):

```
//must be a separate line/variable/object for the initializer
int[,] b = {{1, 2}, {5, 8}, {3, 40}, {6, 3}, {15, 12}, {1, 5}}; 
var c = Coord.SeqFrom2DIntArray(c).ToArray();
```

Which is **very** close to the original request and doesn't even need C# 9's new toys.